# What does [(e) | e <- list, x /= e] in haskell

Tags: haskell

What does [(e) | e <- list, x /= e] in this haskell code?

```
perms :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
perms [] = [[]]
perms list = do
   x <- list
   tails <- perms [(e) | e <- list, x /= e]
   return (x:tails)
```

Comment: The term you'll want to use for searching is "list comprehension".

Comment: BTW, the parentheses around the `e` are completely superfluous. What's not superfluous though is indentation; always make sure something like a `do` block is indented.

Comment: Personally I would find the list monad harder to understand than the list comprehension. Although list comprhension is basically a list monad with *cleaner* syntax.

Comment: Also it should be noted that this implementation of the permutations function returns incorrect results when the input list contains duplicates

Answer (score 3):

The expression

```
[(e) | e <- list, x /= e]
```

is a *list comprehension*, which is a construct to create a new list from some existing ones.

It returns the list made of all elements `(e)` generated by taking every `e` from `list`, taking only those for which `x /= e`.

In this case, the resulting list is `list` where all `x` values have been removed.

The whole list comprehension is equivalent to `filter (x /=) list`.

I would recommend to read a [Haskell tutorial on list comprehensions](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#im-a-list-comprehension).